# How to Run an External jar file from within a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jar, firefox-addon

Here is the code I have so far...

```
        // Run the external encryption process
        var fileExe = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
        fileExe.initWithPath("~/tmp/Encrypt.jar");
        var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                          .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        process.init(fileExe);
        var args = ["java -jar Encrypt.jar -e toEncrypt"];

        process.run(true, args, args.length);

        document.getElementById('hello-world-status-bar-icon').label = "DONE";
```

This currently does not work. Any suggestions??

EDIT
I've also tried..

```
// Run the external encryption process
var fileExe = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
fileExe.initWithPath("java");
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        process.init(fileExe);

 var args = new Array();
        args[0] = " -jar";
        args[1] = "~/tmp/Encrypt.jar";
        args[2] = "-e";
        args[3] = "toEncrypt";

        process.run(true, args, args.length);

        document.getElementById('hello-world-status-bar-icon').label = "DONE";
```

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: The executable you need to run is "java", not the jar file, right?

Comment: ALso, this seems like a pretty weird thing to do, but I don't know anything about your extension of course.

Comment: Its a runnable jar file. From the terminal I run, "java -jar ~/tmp/Encrypt.jar -e toEncrypt" to encrypt it. This is how my encryption works, lots quicker in java than javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to init the process with a reference to the local file that is the "java" executable. That's what needs to be executed at the system level. The arguments need to be passed as an array of individual strings, not a single string.